# vb.net Changing datagridview column header name

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a problem when try to change datagridview`s column header name.

After i changed the column header name from name Column 1 to Year i am trying to get the value of the cell of that column with command

1. row.cells("HEADERNAME").value

and it says that Year column cannot be found. I tried the command to row.cells("Column1").value after is changed to Year and it works .

whys that ? is there anything else i have to do in order to save changes ? i can see that the column header name is changed normaly.

Comment: Show the code where you change the name of the column.

Comment: DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderCell.Value = "VALUE"

Comment: If you want to change the name of a column, use the **name** property: `Me.DataGridView1.Columns(i).Name = "Year"`

Answer (score 1):

The *text in the header*, and the *column name* are two different entities. Changing one does not automatically change the other.

You should refer to the column by it's name, as you have discovered:

```
row.Cells("Column1").Value
```

Alternatively, if you want to change the name of the column, you can do so. Assuming you have an underlying DataTable as a data source:

```
dataTable.Columns("Column1").Name = "MyNewName"
```

If it's not a data table, you should be able to change the name directly in the DataGridView:

```
dataGridView.Columns("Column1").Name = "MyNewName"
```

Comment: so how i can change the header text and also the actual column name of a column ?

Comment: No i dont have a datatable because i just load a csv file to datagrid and then i want to get the value according to the changed column name to insert it to my sql table